# Odd or even permutation with matrices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, parity

I know that the number of transpositions would determine the parity of a permutation like:

A = (1,2,3,4,5) = (1,5),(1,4),(1,3),(1,2) = even

But how would that apply to a matrix?

Example:

> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
>
> 4  2  1  6  5  8  7  3

How would I then transpose these?

Comment: Umm maybe the whole question would help:

Let A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Determine if the following permutation is even or odd
(it's the numbers that are preformatted in the original post).

Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make comparison with each column.

1.Starting from the first column, you have $1\rightarrow4$.

2.Then seek which column top has $4$, which is the fourth column and you have $4\rightarrow6$, etc...

3.Eventually you have $(14683)$ for the first cycle.

4.Then check if any other element left in this cycle. Take one if you have and repeat the previous progress.

Comment: So (1,4),(4,6),(6,8),(8,3) which would make it an even permutation?

Comment: @JurgenMalinao, maybe you should answer Andres Caranti's question first. I am not sure I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @JurgenMalinao, if my post is answering your question, then $(14683)$ is considered as ONE permutation. Since its length is odd, it is an even permutation. (It has nothing to do with (1,4)(4,6)..., you can't write this.)

Comment: I made a new comment to Andres Caranti's question, hope that helps!

Comment: @JurgenMalinao, yes, so I think I am answering on the right way. Is it clear enough to you or you still have any problem?

Comment: Umm why'd you choose 1→4 first? Is it because of the 4 under the first 1 or the 4 in the same column as the 1?

Comment: @JurgenMalinao, theoretically it doesn't matter where you start from, but it would be easier to start from the first column so you don't miss any element in the end. For each colum you have the top number as the preimage and bottom element as the image, that's how a cycle is defined.

Comment: So would another permutation be (4238)? And would that make it odd?

Comment: @JurgenMalinao, if considering just a single cycle, the parity of the permutation will be always opposite to the parity of the length of the cycle. That is, if the length is even, then the permutation is odd, and vice versa.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8455/discussion-between-jurgen-malinao-and-easy)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to determine the parity of a permutation if it is written in [Cauchy's two-line notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Notation), right?

There are several methods. 
You can write the permutation, $\sigma$, in [cycle notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation), lets say $\sigma=(a_1,a_2\ldots,a_{r_1})(b_1,b_2\ldots,b_{r_2})\ldots (c_1,c_2\ldots,c_{r_k})$. Then the parity of $\sigma$ is the parity of $(r_1+1)+(r_2+1)+\ldots+(r_k+1)\in\mathbb N$.

Or, if the permutation is $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&\ldots&n\\
s_1&s_2&\ldots&s_n
\end{pmatrix}$, 
then the parity of $\sigma$ is the parity of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\operatorname{card}(L_{s_i})$ where $L_{s_i}$ are the sets 
$$
L_{s_i}=\{s_j:j=i+1,i+2,\ldots,n, \ s_i<s_1\}.
$$
In your example $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
4&2&1&6&5&8&7&3
\end{pmatrix}$ and
 $L_{4}=\{2,1,3\},\ 
L_2=\{1\}, \ L_1=\emptyset, \ L_6=\{5,3\}, \ L_5=\{3\}, \ L_8=\{7,3\}, \ L_7=\{3\}$. Therefore $\sigma$ is even.